# Getting TFSBuild.proj from TFS 2008 to work on TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I just copied my Solution from TFS 2008 to TFS 2012. In TFS 2008 the TFSBuild.proj does the normal solution building, calls installshield projects, dotfuscator projects and dumps the resulting installshield output in the drop folder.

In my Build Definition I set the "Items to Build" to point to the .proj file. The build works, but all I get is one folder with the logs inside. I added the .sln to build (although didn't need to previously) and get the .sln files built but installshield and dotfuscator are not done.

Looking at the .proj log file... None of my "Message" outputs are there. Was there some large change between these two versions that would necessitate a big change in the proj file?

I do not have admin rights to the TFS servers. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using the "Default" build process template. You need to use the "[Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd647548.aspx#upgrade_template)" template if you want to use a TFSbuild.proj file.

Edit your build definition and go to the "Process" tab. There should be an area that shows which template you are using. Click on the "show details" button and choose the "Upgrade Template" from the drop down list.

Now point the build at the folder containing the TFSbuild.proj and save the definition. This should solve the problem.